how do I know if ios LargeText zoom has been set in safari?
window.devicePixelRatio in safari vs others:
I get back some nice values of:
// 4.0
// 3.3333333333333335
// 3.0
// 2.6086956521739134
// 2.2222222222222223
// 2.0
// 1.8181818181818181
// 1.5789473684210527
// 1.3333333333333333
// 1.0
// 0.6

in firefox or chrome for the currently zoomed in value window.devicePixelRatio but in safari it's just alwasy 2.0 for me.
ios setting img
I'm looking to know this value so if there user on ios has set zoom to Larger Text I'll know. This isn't a resize screen event they enter the safari page with their devicePixelRatio already at 4.0 or something big but I can't see to know that?


In Safari devicePixelRatio will never change. See MDN devicePixelRatio or webkit bug report.

This question is similar to: How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
